# How to use a for loop to move through a range of values and save each iteration as a csv file

Tags: python, list, for-loop, timer, webots

I am trying to actuate a robotic arm with a finger gripper using Webots by Cyberbotics.
I want the forces, in the `forcelist`, to be consecutively tested in the for loop. For example, I want the first value of `i` to be 1000, then 1250, then 1500, until 5000.
When I run my code it seems to only execute the first force value in the for loop and then repeats the for loop using the same value. I am not sure why this is.
I am also trying to record data from each test (each force value iteration) and I am trying to export each test as a separate `csv` file, however my code places all the data in the same, first excel file?
I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

```
forcelist = range(1000, 5000, 250)

for i in forcelist:
    with open(f"TwoFingerGripper_force={i}_mass={MASS}_width={BOX_WIDTH}.csv", 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["dsc_value","com_x","com_y","com_z","speed_lin_x","speed_lin_y","speed_lin_z",                                   "speed_rot_0", "speed_rot_1", "speed_rot_2", "gripper_force", "power_input", "battery"])
        


        # Main loop:
        while robot.step(timestep) != -1:

            if timer < 60:
                finger_motor.setTorque(0.5)
                
            elif timer < 120:
                finger_motor.setForce(i)
                if arm_pos <= 1.6:
                    arm_pos += 0.04
            
            elif timer < 180:
                finger_motor.setForce(i)
                if wst_pos <= 3.14159265:
                    wst_pos += 0.1
        
            elif timer < 240:
                finger_motor.setForce(i)
                if wst_pos > 0:
                    wst_pos -= 0.1
        
            elif timer < 300:
                finger_motor.setForce(i)
                if arm_pos > 0:
                    arm_pos -= 0.04
        
            elif timer < 360:
                if fgr_pos < 0:
                    fgr_pos += 0.02
            
            elif timer > 380:
                timer == 0 
            
            timer += 1  

            ledCtrl()    
            arm_motor.setPosition(arm_pos)
            wrist_motor.setPosition(wst_pos)
            finger_motor.setPosition(-fgr_pos)
```

Please could someone help, I have been stuck on this for quite some time now.

Answer (score 0):

```
forcelist = range(1000, 5000, 250)

for i in forcelist:
    with open(f"TwoFingerGripper_force={i}_mass={MASS}_width={BOX_WIDTH}.csv", 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["dsc_value", "com_x", "com_y", "com_z", "speed_lin_x", "speed_lin_y", "speed_lin_z", "speed_rot_0", "speed_rot_1", "speed_rot_2", "gripper_force", "power_input", "battery"])

        while robot.step(timestep) != -1:
            if timer < 60:
                finger_motor.setTorque(0.5)

            elif timer < 120:
                finger_motor.setForce(i)
                if arm_pos <= 1.6:
                    arm_pos += 0.04

            elif timer < 180:
                finger_motor.setForce(i)
                if wst_pos <= 3.14159265:
                    wst_pos += 0.1

            elif timer < 240:
                finger_motor.setForce(i)
                if wst_pos > 0:
                    wst_pos -= 0.1

            elif timer < 300:
                finger_motor.setForce(i)
                if arm_pos > 0:
                    arm_pos -= 0.04

            elif timer < 360:
                if fgr_pos < 0:
                    fgr_pos += 0.02

            elif timer > 380:
                timer == 0

            timer += 1

            ledCtrl()
            arm_motor.setPosition(arm_pos)
            wrist_motor.setPosition(wst_pos)
            finger_motor.setPosition(-fgr_pos)

            data_row = [dsc_value, com_x, com_y, com_z, speed_lin_x, speed_lin_y, speed_lin_z, speed_rot_0, speed_rot_1, speed_rot_2, gripper_force, power_input, battery]
            writer.writerow(data_row)
```